# Why would this kind of iteration fail?

Tags: c#, debugging

[image]

It's very clear in the debugger that the dictionary is populated with the values; so why does it not even ENTER the loop at all? I've tried stepping through and I get nothing. It just skips over the loop. Period. I use similar techniques elsewhere and have no issues. This is all on the same thread so I don't understand.

You can see a video of some of the frustration here: http://youtu.be/XernyY5-BAo

Comment: Interesting question. What's the type of `Values` property?

Comment: Can you let us know what version of .Net you're running? What VS version as well?

Comment: @niaher - you can see in the the picture, it is an array of Dream.World.Entities.Player

Comment: @Hogan Probably not an array; more likely to be an IList<T> where T is either Player or some base class of Player.

Comment: .NET Framework is 4 (Client Profile); Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I'd also like to make it clear that 'Entities' is a dictionary of <GUID, Entity>

Comment: Might be an unusual request, but does it enter the loop in Release mode? (i.e. when you're not debugging)?

Comment: Runs the same in release mode.

Comment: @Hogan That's the type of of `Values[0]`, but I am actually wondering about the `Values` itself. Just thinking that if it's a custom collection of some sort, then maybe the enumerator was implemented incorrectly? (Kinda far fetched though I guess)

Comment: Have you got it wrapped in a TCF block so you can see if it throws any exception?  What is the second object in the Values?

Comment: How is your `_map.EntityManager.Entities.Values` being populated? Asynchronously? On another thread? Seems to me like a race condition might be to blame here.

Comment: No TCF block; just in a normal function. Nothing special about it. I'll add full code to the orginal post. 

The mapping (as shown above) is Dictionary<Guid, Entity>

Comment: @spender The list is NOT modified at all - I can guarantee. It's a game which is single threaded. (And at that instant in the debugger, it shows perfect)

Comment: Can you put `_map.EntityManager.Entities.Count()` and `_map.EntityManager.Entities.Values.Count()` in just before your loop to check they evaluate correctly?

Comment: @BlueChippy             Console.WriteLine(_map.EntityManager.Entities.Count());
            Console.WriteLine(_map.EntityManager.Entities.Values.Count);

The output is 0 and 0

Comment: Is EntityManager your repository?  Debug the code that loads your Entities/Values - if entities is Zero just before you go into the loop the EntityManager normally ISN'T filling the values correctly - although when you manually force it to evaluate in the debugger/watch window it does load.

Comment: They kinda just stream in - this is part of a chat message. The entity is the only one logged in on the local server on this map. The only time the entity would be removed or added is if a player would log in or out. Since I am the only one on my local machine, this is not the case. I stepped through anyway just in case.

Comment: @VaughanHilts I think BlueChippy has nailed it - if the Count returns zero, the iterator won't return anything. I'd dig into the EntityManager implementation as far as you can to see what's happening and why it's different when you check in the debugger.  I still think it could be a race condition...

Comment: Does sound like a race condition of somekind.  Quick top-of-head thought: Have you got anything in the repo which would allow e.g. YOU to see every logged in user, but anything else including the process itself, to only "see" certain users?

Comment: I can confirm the following:

I added a dummy object to the list. The if statement then fires, the debugger claims 'Vaughan' is still the only object in the list - but 'e' has a 'null' name (the default for a blank, unslated Player).

What the heck is going on!? Even if this is a race condition (which I don't believe it should be, but I'll check some more...) why is it just blanking out? The list isn't being cleared for sure because this list is what is used to RENDER the players on screen and that is still defintely there.

Comment: What happens if you try something like 'var temp = _map.EntityManager.Entities.Values;  foreach(player e in temp)'  ?

Comment: The temp list shows up blank

Comment: @Kal_Torak I added some dummy values; and those all succesfully over multiple iterations execute in the loop... however, the debugger still indicates my character is the only one in the dictionary and that those dummy objects are not there.

Comment: Are you using static methods in your repo?  Are you creating a new _map each time, new EntityManager? etc?

Comment: I also just edited the value that appears in the debugger @BlueChippy and it affects the rendering sub-system. This item is indeed staying in the list.

Comment: Simple possibility: they are NOT the same list.  The one you see in the debugger and in the rendering are the same.  The one in the loop and with dummy objects is different...somehow!

Comment: You can see the exact issue here: http://youtu.be/XernyY5-BAo I don't see how this could ever be the case!

Comment: Hopefully I've interpreted your earlier comment right...
The fact that you're manipulating the list and not seeing the changes in the debugger suggests that either it's a different list as @BlueChippy suggested, or there's something funky going on inside your EntityManager. Can you step into the adding of the dummy list item to see how it's being added? Make sure it's not spawning a new thread or something like that?

Comment: @Damovisa The only line is the following 

        public virtual void AddEntity(Entity entity)
        {
            Entities.Add(entity.Identifier, entity);
        }

The "Entites" in this call shows a Count of 0. =(

Comment: ...and there's no override of the method in an inheriting class?  No overrides/base classes for Entity?

Comment: The inheriting class does over-ride it, although it probably shouldn't:         public override void AddEntity(Entity entity)
        {
            base.AddEntity(entity);
        }

But this alone should cause no issues. I've removed it with no luck.

Comment: I could see a situation where inheritance is making two different lists depending on how you instantiate the Manager and the Entity.

Comment: @BlueChippy http://pastebin.com/EwHUTkPY http://pastebin.com/bp846xSv
Not much to see there..

Comment: Multiple instantiations of _map?  Just create an EntityManager on it's own...add yourself and the dummy items...then check?

Comment: They contain the values as expected. However, I feel this isn't a case of multiple instances because before I call 'AddEntity' it displays fine... (or at least my value). As soon as I step in, the values has disappeared...

Comment: So, accessing Map, EntityManager or Entities is creating a new list...try each in turn.

Comment: @BlueChippy How is that possible within one step though of a debugger? And that still dosen't explain why Visual Studio is giving the results it is... =(

Comment: Can you step into each in turn (_map is accessed first...when it accesses it's EntityManager property...check the count before and after. I suspect one of the property getters is either creating a new dictionary or not returning the one it should be returning?

Comment: @BlueChippy There was an issue with the new keyword after playing around for a bit. Thanks a lot for getting me to look elsewhere.

Comment: No worries...we've all spent hours on issues like this at one time or another ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to be **that** guy and answer my own question but I feel like someone else could learn something from my error.

It turns out, the EntityManager from the base class was implemented separately by the base class in this case, it was over-ridden with the **new** keyword. This was causing the lists to separate and cause all sorts of ugly issues. Don't hide your inheritance trees, everyone! Always double check your implementations! Thanks for all the help everyone; I still don't know why Visual Studio was displaying different values than it should have so if anyone has any information pertaining to why this might be the case - I'll mark you best answer!

Answer (score 2):

I expect the `name == e.Name` is false

The compiler probably optimized stepping in this case.

or maybe `name` is null and it has an exception?

Comment: It doesn't enter the loop to get that far.

Comment: +1 for mentioning optimisation - I tried this out with a similar example and the debugger did not even enter the loop in Release mode.

Comment: @BradleySmith I wish this was the case... but I just tried copying the List with ToList() and I receive the same results. :(